# Python cgkit installation from source error

Tags: python, cgkit

I'm trying to build Python CGKit from source. I've performed the scons step, then when I try to install it using

```
python setup.py install
```

I get a bunch of warnings as the files compile and one error that causes the build to fail. The error reads:

```
supportlib/include/slot.h:549:5: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const boost::python::api::object')
```

I've looked online a bunch and can't seem to find a fix for this issue. Can someone advise me on how to go about fixing this?

Thanks,

Siddharth